# Could not load the emoji font in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fonts, emoji

I would like to plot Apple emoji in matplotlib, so I wrote this code.
However, I get an error that could not set the font size when setting fonts.
If I do not set the font it will be plotted like the next image. [image of plotting emoji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvoG9.png)

My system is Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6, my matplotlib version is 2.0.2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

prop = FontProperties(fname='/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc')
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()

plt.annotate("", (0.5, 0.3), size=30)
plt.annotate("", (0.5, 0.8), size=30)
plt.savefig("emoji_test.png")
```

> File "./emoji_test.py", line 5, in
>
> plt.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 750, in get_name
>
> return get_font(findfont(self)).family_name
>
> RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Could not set the fontsize

Comment: I think matplotlib has rather limited support of ttc fonts. No matter what, it will sure not be able to show color in fonts.

Comment: See [here](http://catherineh.github.io/programming/2017/10/24/emoji-data-markers-in-matplotlib) for how to use normal images instead

Comment: Same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102873/how-to-plot-high-quality-emoji-in-matplotlib

Comment: I tried ttf fonts, however the result was same. And I used images instead of emoji (same method that you suggested), but I'd like to use emoji fonts because the picture quality is bad.

Comment: I found the issue from stackoverflow question that you suggested. [Emoji missing when use plt.savefig](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4492/) Emoji can be displayed in this issue, but can not be reproduced in own environment.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest you edit the question to use the code you got from that quesiton and the issue you have using it. Still I think this is not using `ttc` font, but `ttf`.

Comment: Thank you very much for researching out variously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop.get_family()` rather than `prop.get_name()` since you're setting the **font family** not the **font name**

the code becomes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

prop = FontProperties(fname='/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc')
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_family()

plt.annotate("", (0.5, 0.3), size=30)
plt.annotate("", (0.5, 0.8), size=30)
plt.savefig("emoji_test.png")
```

The resulting figure is below
[image]

PS. The error message is due to a known issue. see [RuntimeError In FT2Font with NISC18030.ttf](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7305/)

Comment: Where is the difference between this plot and the one from the question?

Comment: explained at the beginning of my post

Comment: Thank you for telling me! I expect that graph is drawn Apple Color Emoji font, but output graph is not Apple emoji. Do you know this solution?

Comment: I would like to draw like this graph. [emoji graph](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8574101/7972028/3380c8da-09fe-11e5-9df4-a564cc6f757e.png)